# Select a row with preceding and following rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE results (
  id uuid primary key UNIQUE,
  score integer NOT NULL
)
```

I need to select a record with particular UUID and what's around it (say, 5 before and after) ordered by score

```
SELECT * FROM results
WHERE id = <SOME_UUID>
ORDERED BY score
OFFSET -5 LIMIT 10; -- apparently this is wrong
```

How can I effectively do that?

Answer (score 0):

Its not 'effective', but you could try this:

```
select a.* from (SELECT * FROM results
WHERE id <> <SOME_UUID> and score <= (select score from results WHERE id = <SOME_UUID>)
ORDERED BY score,id desc
LIMIT 5) as a

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM results
WHERE id = <SOME_UUID>

UNION ALL
select b.* from (SELECT * FROM results
WHERE id <> <SOME_UUID> and score >= (select score from results WHERE id = <SOME_UUID>)
ORDERED BY score, id asc
LIMIT 5) as b
```

I tried this an SQL-Server, which needded the 'ALL' to compute.
So you may get records with equal score as duplicates. To avoid this make it again to a subquery and use select distinct.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is with a rank for each row assigned using a window function and then finding out which ranks you are interested in:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT id, score, rank() OVER (ORDER BY score) AS rnk
  FROM results),
this_rank AS (
  SELECT rnk - 5 AS low_rnk FROM ranked
  WHERE id = <some uuid>::uuid)
SELECT id, score
FROM ranked, this_rank
WHERE rnk >= low_rnk
ORDER BY rnk
LIMIT 11;
```

For very low or high scores you get fewer than 11 rows, rather than rows with `NULL`s.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63cd1)

One further detail: A `PRIMARY KEY` already implies uniqueness so you do not have to use the `UNIQUE` clause in your table definition.